# how to get updated state value after updating in a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I'm trying to get login user detail. I need to put data to state and used the same state for further processing it takes time to put data to state and use this data. nearly it takes 2- 3 sec to use the state with that data.

I solved this issue if we use `setTimeOut()` function with 3 sec so that we it updates data in this time. if we don't use `setTimeOut()` and use state wright after updating it then it will provide initial data of the state.

```
complete_date = date + ":" + month + ":" + year;

var query = firebase.database().ref('attendence/'+ complete_date +"/").orderByKey();

email_match=false;
entry_time =null,
l_id = null,

query.on("value",(data)=> 
{
  data.forEach(function(childs) 
  {
    l_id = childs.key;
      // __ to check if the user already loged in before.
    var att_query = firebase.database().ref('attendence/'+ complete_date +"/"+ l_id).orderByKey();
    att_query.once("value",(data)=> 
    {
      if(email == data.child('email').val())
      {
        email_match =  true;
        entry_time = data.child('timeEntry').val();
      }
    }); //  
  });  // 

  this.setState({ last_id:l_id });
  this.setState({ emailMatchState:email_match });
  this.setState({alreayLogedState : entry_time});

}); // _____end of query.on("value",(data)=> 

setTimeout(() => 
{
console.log("-----------------------------------");
console.log("already logged :",this.state.alreayLogedState," email match :",this.state.emailMatchState , " result  : ", this.state.result , " last_id :",st.last_id);
console.log("-----------------------------------");
},3000);
```

I need to use state after updating without the use of `setTimeout()` for faster working of the application.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument for `setState` is a `callback` to execute when all updates are done

```
 this.setState({ last_id:l_id }, () => console.log(this.state.last_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

setState takes an optional second argument that gets called after the updates to the state object have taken place.

example:

```
let callback = () => {
 // do something
}

this.setState({
 keyToUpdate: valueToUpdate
}, callback)
```

Additional reading about the use of this callback:
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296?gi=18aa91e88437

Also, unless something is happening in between the seperate calls, these:

```
this.setState({ last_id:l_id });
this.setState({ emailMatchState:email_match });
this.setState({alreayLogedState : entry_time});
```

can be simplified to this:

```
this.setState({ 
 last_id:l_id,
 emailMatchState: email_match, 
 alreayLogedState: entry_time
}); //optionally add callback
```